# Android Socket sending data to WPF application

Tags: java, android, wpf, sockets, tcp

So i have a registration Android app that in main activity creates a socket connection on create opensocket().  Everything runs perfectly on the first submit, the debugger out put looks great and it sends/recieves data back from my WPF app.  Now It goes to a thanks activity which onclick leads back to my mainactivity.  Now when i hit submit, it works fine, but is showing its hitting my socket methods twice (only inserts the records once on my WPF app) , and so on as many times i submit.  I realize i'm not closing or reusing my socket connection correctly?!  I've tried several things, but can't seem to get this to either reuse the same opensocket instance or can't just close and reopen on reload.  I'm quite new to android and sockets all together, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        settingsCheck();

        openSocket();

        sett.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                launchSettings();
        }

        });
        mainLogo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RefreshMain();
        }

        });




        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {




            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv_errors.setText("");
                errorMsg = "";
                nameCheck(et_lName.getText().toString(),et_fName.getText().toString());
                emailCheck(et_email.getText().toString());
                partnerCheck();
                mobileCheck(et_mobile.getText().toString());
                if (SocketHandler.SocketConnected){
                    if(errorMsg == ""){
                        //tv_errors.setText("");
                        if(checkForSD() == true){
                        sendRegistrantInfo(et_fName.getText() + "," + et_lName.getText() + "," + et_email.getText() + "," + et_mobile.getText() + "," + et_partEmail.getText() + "," + cb_terms1.isChecked() + "," + cb_terms2.isChecked() );
                        }
                        else{

                            tv_errors.setText("**Please insert an SD Card.");

                        }
                    }
                    else{


                        //tv_errors.setText(errorMsg);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    connectionStatus.setText("Connection Error.");

                    tv_errors.setText("**Connection lost, please try again.");
                    //openSocket();

                }


            }
        });



    }
    public void RefreshMain()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    public void launchLogin()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }//end launchLogin
    public void launchSettings()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }//end launchSettings

    public void settingsCheck()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentIP = settings.getString("IPSetting", "");
        String currentPort = settings.getString("PORTSetting", "");
        currentMem = settings.getString("SDSize", "");
        if (currentIP == "" || currentPort == ""){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    }//end settingsCheck()



    public void launchRingDialog(String id) {

        final String idYo = id;       
        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Formatting SD Card","Formatting SD Card, please wait this could take several minutes...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override

                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            fileToSD(idYo);
                            Thread.sleep(10000);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                       }

                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }).start();

            }
    public boolean checkForSD()
    {
        String root = "/storage/removable/sdcard1/";
        double memInGigs = round(sizeMatters(root),2);

        if(memInGigs >0){
        return true;
        }
        else
        {

        return false;
        }
    }



    private double sizeMatters(String path)
    {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
        double availSize = (double)stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (double)stat.getBlockSize();

        double ingigs = availSize/ 1073741824;
        return ingigs;

    }//end sizeMatters()

    private void sendRegistrantInfo(String reg){ 
        _sh.sendMessage(reg);
    } 

    private void openSocket(){

        _sh = new SocketHandler();
        _sh.setSocketHandlerListener(this);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentIP = settings.getString("IPSetting", "");
        String currentPort = settings.getString("PORTSetting", "");
        _sh.open(currentIP, currentPort);
    }

    @Override  
    protected void onPause() {  
        super.onPause();  

    }  
        @Override  
    protected void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();  

    }

    @Override
    public void onSocketConnected() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onSocketConnected");
       connectionStatus.setText("CONNECTED");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSocketData(String msg) {

        Log.v(TAG, "onSocketData - " + msg );
        int usrID = Integer.parseInt(msg.trim());
        if (msg != null & usrID > 0){
            launchRingDialog(msg);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThanksActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(msg.trim().equals("-2") == true)
        {
            tv_errors.setText("**This email has already been registered for this event, please click Already Registered button to sign in.");
        }
        else{

        tv_errors.setText("**Error, Please try submitting again.");
        errorMsg = "-1";
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onSocketDisconnected() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onSocketDisconnected");
        connectionStatus.setText("DISCONNECTED");

    }




    public class SocketHandler {

        Socket sc;
        public static boolean SocketConnected = false;
        private static ClientThread cThread;

        public String prefsFile = "prefs";
        public String port = "8888";
        public String ip = "192.168.1.4";


        private String TAG = "SocketHandler";
        protected SocketHandlerListener socketHandlerListener;

        public interface SocketHandlerListener{
            public void onSocketConnected();
            public void onSocketData(String msg);
            public void onSocketDisconnected();
        }

        public SocketHandler(){

        }

        public void setSocketHandlerListener(SocketHandlerListener shl){
            socketHandlerListener = shl;
        }

        public void open(String ip, String port){
            this.ip = ip; 
            this.port = port;
            cThread = new ClientThread();
            try{
                cThread.start();    
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.v(TAG, "Error connecting to socket");

            }
        }

        public void close(){
            if (cThread != null){
                if (cThread.socket != null){
                    try {
                        cThread.socket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Error closing socket");
                    }
                    cThread.socket = null;  
                }
            }
        }


        public void sendMessage(String msg){
            cThread.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        public void messageRecieved(String msg){
            dispatchSocketData(msg);
        }

        private void dispatchSocketConnected(){
            if (socketHandlerListener != null){
                socketHandlerListener.onSocketConnected();
            }
        }

        private void dispatchSocketDisconnected(){
            if (socketHandlerListener != null){
                socketHandlerListener.onSocketDisconnected();
            }
        }

        private void dispatchSocketData(String msg){
            if (socketHandlerListener != null){
                socketHandlerListener.onSocketData(msg);
            }
        }

        public  class ClientThread extends Thread {
            public  Socket socket; 

            public void run() {
                try {



                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                    Log.v(TAG, "C: Connecting..." + ip + ":" + port);
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Integer.parseInt(port));
                    socket.setSoTimeout(0);
                    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                    SocketConnected = true;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dispatchSocketConnected();

                        }
                    });

                    // BLOCKING THE THREAD
                    while (SocketConnected) {
                       InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int line = in.read(buffer, 0, 4096);

                        while (line != -1) {

                            byte[] tempdata = new byte[line];
                            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tempdata, 0, line);
                           final String data = new String(tempdata);

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    messageRecieved(data);
                                    SocketConnected = false;
                                }
                            });
                            line = in.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                        }

                       // break;

                    }
                    socket.close();

                    Log.v("Socket", "C: Closed.");
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dispatchSocketDisconnected();

                        }
                    });
                    SocketConnected = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Socket", "C: Error", e);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dispatchSocketDisconnected();

                        }
                    });
                    SocketConnected = false; 
                }
            }

            Handler handler = new Handler();


            public  void sendMessage(String msg){

                if (socket != null){
                    if (socket.isConnected()){
                        PrintWriter out;
                        try {
                            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), false);
                            out.print(msg);
                            out.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SocketConnected=false;` is on the wrong place. That should be after socket.close(). Remove the // of the following `//break;` as you are done there. Dont name your variable `line` where you mean `bytesRead`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!  had to change my while loop condition a little as well, you steered me in the right direction